# Margin on every page with @page css

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically generated HTML page that has to be saved as pdf. The page has border that has to appear on the edge of the page thus in the `@media print`, I have set the `@page` size as A4 and margins as 0. The problem is that the content will get overwritten on the page border.

When I set the padding to the border, the top of the page first page gets properly printed but the content gets overwritten on the border at the bottom and in the remaining pages.

This can be clearly seen as shown in the images below.

[image: Look at the ending]

**Since I gave padding to the top border, the top of the first page is fine but not the bottom.**

[image: Look at the top and the bottom]

**In this second page, the entire content gets inside the margin.**

Here is the HTML for the same document.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#pageborder {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 10px solid #F5821F;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#pageborder2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 10px solid #F5821F;

  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#pageborder3 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #F5821F;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}


#innerContent {
  margin: 50px;
}

@media print {
  @page{
    margin: 0;
  }

  #pageborder3 {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageborder">
 </div>

 <div id="pageborder2">
 </div>
 <div id="pageborder3">
 </div>

 <div id='innerContent'>

  <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination between `page-break-inside: avoid` and padding/margin on paragraphs will do the trick.

This will look strange if there are very large paragraph around the page break, as this will make a big gap at the bottom of the page, so you should divide the text in smaller paragraphs.

```css
/* I have removed your pageborder styles from answer to only include 
   the relevant styles for the solution to the problem. */


  @page{
    size:  A4;
    margin: 0;
  }

#innerContent {
  /* This is the margin around the content */
  margin: 50px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, .flow-control 
/* Add any element types here that can occur as top element in the document flow 
   or just add class="flow-control" where needed */ 
{
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Make sure no page breake inside a paragraph */
  padding-top: 50px; /* Creates a buffer to enlarge the area for page break. 
            This is also the visual padding for the firs paragraph on each page. */
  margin-top: -50px; /* Cancel the top padding for all except the first paragraph on each page. */
}

h1, h2{
  margin-top: -20px; /* Reduce the cancelling of top padding, so that 
                        these elements actually will have some top padding */
}
 
p { 
  padding-bottom: 20px; /* This is the margin between paragraphs and also 
                           works as buffer size at bottom of the page */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pageborder" id="pageborder1"></div>
<div class="pageborder" id="pageborder2"></div>
<div class="pageborder" id="pageborder3"></div>

<article id='innerContent'>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<section>
  <blockquote  cite="https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/De_finibus_bonorum_et_malorum/Liber_Primus">
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...
  </blockquote >
  <blockquote cite="https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-lorem-ipsum-text">
    There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain...
  </blockquote >
</section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo quis elementum elementum, dui dolor accumsan ligula, vitae condimentum est magna a dui. Praesent accumsan mi eget augue cursus, vel maximus ante cursus. Nullam luctus massa gravida ipsum luctus dignissim. In eget turpis ut sapien consequat euismod. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac porttitor nisl. Fusce ac sapien eget lacus gravida pharetra non id risus. Donec luctus finibus commodo. Cras convallis in nunc a venenatis. Curabitur at nisi nec nisl semper sagittis sed vel sem.</p>
<p>Sed dictum massa quam, nec bibendum neque egestas non. Ut mattis lacus nisi, gravida hendrerit erat scelerisque sit amet. Nulla eget leo venenatis eros rhoncus bibendum et at quam. Morbi ac leo convallis, maximus velit et, porttitor justo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec aliquam ultricies nunc, vitae dapibus sapien sollicitudin non. Pellentesque ac diam ut odio posuere efficitur non finibus ante. Vivamus aliquam leo a suscipit finibus. Mauris a ex metus. Phasellus luctus augue sit amet ipsum venenatis, at imperdiet nunc sollicitudin. Cras iaculis lorem ac justo posuere, sed venenatis nibh fringilla.</p>
<p>Duis imperdiet euismod sem, id dignissim erat gravida vel. Duis nec nibh lectus. Donec in rhoncus sapien. Nulla nisi nisl, gravida at vulputate at, ornare id tortor. Nulla varius ligula ac turpis porta, non tristique leo efficitur. Quisque suscipit, est ut aliquam interdum, mi nulla pharetra metus, imperdiet imperdiet ex sapien sed metus. Integer sit amet lectus ut justo tincidunt laoreet sit amet ac ipsum.</p>
<p>Donec mollis tempus cursus. Mauris et tincidunt ante. Nam leo ex, volutpat non velit ac, imperdiet luctus tellus. Vestibulum vitae consectetur mauris, eu imperdiet dolor. Vestibulum viverra mi id diam viverra, at convallis ex bibendum. Nam mollis feugiat pulvinar. Maecenas neque ipsum, consequat a iaculis at, semper in ipsum. Vivamus a porta sapien. Fusce pulvinar, nulla at euismod semper, ipsum arcu vestibulum orci, sed egestas lectus odio et mi. Sed venenatis felis accumsan, consectetur orci sed, convallis risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin mattis, orci ac rutrum lobortis, odio tellus euismod mi, et scelerisque tellus massa ut risus.</p>
<p>Aenean in elit vitae risus pharetra suscipit eu sed risus. Maecenas sollicitudin nunc ac lacus fermentum tincidunt. Maecenas a pretium ipsum. In viverra eros sit amet lectus eleifend, at auctor velit mollis. Proin aliquam risus vel arcu pellentesque, eget volutpat justo facilisis. Nunc in ex tellus. Mauris euismod luctus commodo. Pellentesque arcu justo, aliquam ut quam in, egestas dapibus ante. Morbi facilisis mi nec leo semper laoreet. Aenean ac dolor vel erat suscipit vulputate. Praesent sit amet eleifend libero, sit amet viverra lorem. Ut eleifend lectus non tempus placerat. Praesent magna ipsum, porta sit amet mattis vel, condimentum eleifend magna.</p>
<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas velit tortor, faucibus vitae rhoncus eget, laoreet vel sem. Proin interdum ut risus a tempor. Aliquam malesuada, tellus et luctus iaculis, est est aliquet nisl, volutpat elementum augue nunc ut lorem. Nulla facilisis ipsum vestibulum, iaculis magna in, maximus libero. Suspendisse tortor odio, euismod nec leo placerat, mattis varius elit. Suspendisse a ipsum vehicula, viverra metus eget, scelerisque dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus a sapien eget felis mollis imperdiet.</p>
<p>Sed accumsan eu dolor nec vestibulum. Aenean interdum porttitor mattis. Curabitur finibus, erat nec posuere luctus, elit nisi imperdiet neque, eget maximus nulla dolor at justo. In sem odio, feugiat quis condimentum id, sodales id felis. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum odio ex, blandit vel ullamcorper ac, tincidunt et justo. Vestibulum congue congue vehicula. Praesent tempor tortor ut tellus vulputate hendrerit. Proin lectus ante, dapibus eu laoreet varius, dictum sit amet lacus.</p>
<p>Integer vel mollis justo, quis commodo diam. Morbi cursus mauris nibh. Proin vestibulum ornare turpis, in consequat tellus condimentum quis. Praesent nulla magna, commodo sit amet molestie a, sollicitudin laoreet elit. Fusce ut augue vitae ligula commodo mattis sit amet non augue. Nulla a lectus purus. Sed sed consequat magna, in tempus quam. Cras sed consectetur nulla, tempus luctus ligula. Proin porttitor porttitor nisl, quis pretium turpis imperdiet id. Fusce commodo nulla sem, vitae gravida nulla molestie eu. Donec accumsan ex eget faucibus luctus. Ut leo eros, accumsan id aliquam et, aliquet at tellus.</p>
<p>Proin fringilla congue metus, ac semper ex aliquam ullamcorper. Integer porttitor tempor leo ac elementum. Vivamus a nisi vitae tellus interdum rhoncus. Nam eleifend ipsum sit amet enim feugiat, vitae pulvinar elit dignissim. </p>
<p>Vivamus tempus felis enim, non fermentum erat venenatis a. Morbi dolor ante, iaculis in nulla sit amet, eleifend aliquam nisl. Phasellus ultrices turpis ut ipsum molestie, a euismod sem venenatis. Duis a leo ac quam gravida sagittis nec vitae dui. Proin pellentesque, nulla sed fringilla malesuada, dui erat dignissim ex, eget sollicitudin enim purus pellentesque risus. Aenean a porta lacus, nec ullamcorper tellus.</p>
<div class="flow-control"><!-- This is to make sure there are no page brake 
                           between the header and next paragraph -->
 <h2>Header test</h2>
 <p>Curabitur eros metus, maximus ornare mollis suscipit, commodo sed erat. Suspendisse dolor lectus, suscipit auctor risus a, malesuada auctor magna. Cras erat augue, venenatis luctus erat ac, ultrices pretium tellus. Mauris faucibus convallis euismod. Mauris tincidunt sit amet metus quis mattis. Quisque luctus quam rutrum mollis mollis. Donec velit tortor, iaculis in mattis sed, consequat vitae ligula. Vestibulum tempus lacinia blandit. Integer eleifend lacus id lorem feugiat, at varius sapien accumsan. Nam fermentum hendrerit lorem, et euismod diam tincidunt sit amet. Donec vitae dolor in nunc eleifend tincidunt. Curabitur vel maximus purus. Donec varius lorem justo, a commodo dolor vehicula in. In condimentum risus sed placerat condimentum. Ut enim ex, pellentesque eget metus vel, gravida viverra arcu. Suspendisse interdum leo ac porta vestibulum.</p>
</div>
<p>Fusce ipsum justo, convallis et venenatis id, tincidunt non orci. Nam vestibulum molestie egestas. Vivamus ultricies ultrices fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin sit amet dui porta, tempor nibh finibus, suscipit felis. Aenean rhoncus enim at imperdiet porttitor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce tellus eros, euismod sit amet gravida sit amet, mattis ut tortor. Fusce nec lectus a massa iaculis tempor. Morbi tortor ante, facilisis eget diam suscipit, dignissim pulvinar nulla. Nunc ultrices eros sed facilisis mattis.</p>
<p>Vestibulum lobortis metus velit, id cursus justo viverra id. Sed euismod nisi nunc, id malesuada nulla porttitor ultricies. Quisque cursus ut nisl eu vehicula. Ut a convallis nulla. Maecenas vehicula dolor a dui mattis, non sollicitudin lorem malesuada. Sed faucibus vulputate turpis in fringilla. Donec feugiat dui at nulla iaculis rhoncus. Mauris venenatis congue maximus. Vivamus maximus volutpat dictum. Cras vehicula sodales ante ut viverra.</p>
<p>Vivamus at rutrum justo. Vestibulum vulputate scelerisque convallis. Etiam vulputate nunc tempor tortor varius lobortis. Suspendisse ut posuere augue. Proin nunc metus, fermentum at tincidunt in, gravida ut massa. Curabitur eu ex tristique, accumsan justo in, luctus dui. Praesent a dolor eu tellus gravida lobortis sed ut magna. Nunc feugiat elit ultricies, bibendum lacus nec, cursus elit. Proin facilisis mauris a dolor imperdiet, vel lacinia enim rutrum. Sed tristique ultricies magna ac lobortis. Integer nec varius sapien. Vestibulum convallis finibus enim, sed tincidunt lectus scelerisque quis.</p>
<p>Nam faucibus lorem et ultrices luctus. Aliquam id pharetra nisi. Curabitur malesuada elit eget nisi imperdiet fringilla. Quisque orci eros, pulvinar eget finibus ut, mollis vitae magna. Nulla molestie massa at convallis facilisis. Maecenas sagittis facilisis feugiat. Quisque rutrum, urna at consectetur pellentesque, mauris dolor faucibus nisl, vel tristique leo est vitae magna. Curabitur fermentum dignissim nisi tincidunt rhoncus.</p>
<p>Suspendisse pretium enim volutpat, fringilla urna tempor, dictum metus. Nunc vel purus vel arcu molestie hendrerit. Vestibulum sed mollis mauris. Fusce nisi velit, imperdiet sed porttitor at, elementum at mauris. Quisque at magna volutpat, rhoncus velit volutpat, aliquet dolor. Ut metus ante, commodo non risus sed, congue posuere metus. Mauris a sem metus. Duis accumsan mi non facilisis mollis. Maecenas et dolor eget felis rhoncus pretium. Aenean vitae arcu cursus, ultricies massa vel, congue leo. Proin suscipit nisi odio, malesuada interdum nisi aliquam at. Aliquam ac congue magna.</p>

  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: But even in this case, when my new page starts with the title, the title gets overwritten by the margin. See this [image](https://imgur.com/a/jhGgeNo).

Comment: Se my edited code. The trick with page-brake-inside, padding-top and margin-top should be applied to all element types in the document flow that do not have a parent that has the flow-control already applied. I have also added a class`flow-control` to this style that you can use for controlling sections that is not heading or paragraph.

Comment: I wrap the header and the following paragraph inside a div with class="flow-control" to make sure there are never a page break between the header and the following paagraph. This would always be needed for headers, so if you always do this in the HTML, you will not need to include the headins in the style definition.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines of code in your CSS, it will work :)

```
#pageborder2:after{
     content: "";
    width: 92%;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#pageborder3:after{
    content: "";
    width: 92%;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: By using this solution, the border appears on top of the content but the content is getting overridden by the border.  
As you can see in this image, the heading is behind the margin.  
[Link to the image](https://imgur.com/a/jhGgeNo)